# Authentication in iOS using UITabBarController

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, cocoa

I would like to create a tabBarController with the title "profile" that triggers a login flow if the user is not logged in, or pulls up a certain view controller if not. I can't be the only one in the world who hasn't needed something similar. I tried my hand at something like the following.

```
@implementation ProtectedViewController
//...
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    if (FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded) {
        [self presentViewController: self.targetViewController animated: NO completion: nil];
    } else {
        AppDelegate* appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        [appDelegate showLoginView];
    }
}

+ (ProtectedViewController*)protectedControllerFor:(UIViewController*)viewController
{
    ProtectedViewController* protectedViewController = [[ProtectedViewController alloc] initWithNibName: nil bundle: nil];
    protectedViewController.targetViewController = viewController;
    return protectedViewController;
}
//...

someTabBarController.viewControllers = [feedViewController, [ProtectedViewController protectedControllerFor: newPostController];
```

This feels clunky (and doesn't really work yet). How is this normally done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do this is provide functionality in your appDelegate. If you need a login window, you instantiate it there and make it the rootViewController for the window. Once the user has logged in, you signal the appDelegate, it then creates a tab bar controller, and makes the tabBarController the  rootViewController.

What I did was to fade the loginView out and then the tabBarView in. You will have to experiment to find the best transition.

Comment: I want to allow the app to be accessible without logging in, all the examples show this type of authentication (application will not launch unless you have logged in). I need more a less the equivalent of a traditional website with logged in sections and logged out sections.

Comment: So fine - I did this in a beta - your appDelegate has a property - loggedIn. You let them in, but at all stages look at that flag to decide what they can see. When they finally say, OK, I want to activate an account, have our app delegate swap views as above, let them log in or create an account, then go back to the tab bar controller.

Comment: This is closer, but the viewControllers property of tabBarcontroller only takes instances of viewcontrollers. Is there a way to have code that says, "if the app delegate logged in property is true, then the view controller should be A, otherwise it should be B"?

Comment: No - put the logic in your appDelegate, let it control what view becomes the root view controller, and have it replace one with another when you need to switch.

Comment: how did you do the fade in effect with that approach ?

Comment: @Malloc I overlaid a clear view, then animated it to black, then once the new view was loaded, overlaid a black view over it, faded it to clear, then removed it.

Comment: @DavidH Hi, Are you using UIView animation for that?

Comment: @Malloc yes I am using the UIView animations with a completion block to remove the view or other action.

Comment: @David H, Thanx David. I recommend using the `transitionWithView:duration:options:animations:completion:` method as it provide the most flexible and best user experience following your the window approach. It's also a `UIView` method, not sure if you are referring to that or the `animateWithDuration:` method